# jQuery .ajax() request not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make an AJAX call to my web server to pull down information about a city.

- I have a select drop down on the page, populated with 3 values: [*blank*], "New York, NY", and "Ann Arbor, MI"
- When an item is selected, the city's name is reformatted: spaces are turned into '-'
- Then `.ajax()` is fired to "/data/[*city*]"
- When the server responds, it calls `alert()` with a JSON object it retrieved.

**Code:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#city').change(function () {
    var city = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ /g,"-");
    if(city.length > 0)
    {
      var url = "/data/cities/" + city;
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        context: document.body,
        dataType: 'json'
      }).done(function(data) {
        alert(data);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

For some reason, the `.ajax()` call refuses to fire on occasion. The outgoing HTTP request is never made when `url` equals:

- `/data/cities/New-York,-NY`

However, it fires successfully when `url` equals:

- `/data/cities/New-York-NY` (no comma)
- `/data/cities/New-York,NY` (no dash)
- `/data/cities/New-York,-NYC` (additional character)
- `/data/cities/Ann-Arbor,-MI` (similar format)

I have verified:

- The browser makes no outgoing HTTP request when it 'fails' (as checked via Chromium's Network tab)
- The web server receives the HTTP requests for all the URLs except this problematic one
- There are no Javascript errors on the page

Am I missing something obvious? This seems *really* weird that `.ajax()` wouldn't fire for this one specific URL...

**EDIT:**

Added an error callback to the `.ajax()` request. It is failing with an error of state = "rejected" and statusText = "error".

As requested, the `<select>` tag on the page:

```
<select id="city">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="New York, NY">New York, NY</option>
  <option value="Ann Arbor, MI">Ann Arbor, MI</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Did you try to `console.log(city)`? What's it value after `replace`?

Comment: `New-York,-NY`, as I stated above. (I just ran this in console to double-check.)

Comment: can we have the html o #city ? There must be something wrong with it

Comment: You might try adding error: someErrorFunction to your .ajax() parameters and then implement someErrorFunction() to report back. It might shed some light on the problem. I always use error: someErrorFunction() and success: someSuccessFunction(), rather than .done() -- not sure which is better.

Comment: Btw, if current selected option is `NY` and you choosed `NY` again - `change` event won't be fired. Maybe it is the reason?

Comment: @MaVRoSCy Added HTML above, but I doubt it'd affect the `.ajax()` call itself.

Comment: @u_mulder When the page loads, the currently selected option is [*blank*]. When I select NY it fails. When I select MI, it works. When I select back to NY it fails. Then when I select back to MI again, it works.

Comment: The problem is that request runs but returns nothing? Or it doesn't even starts? Not clear for me from your explanation.

Comment: @Dave What do you mean by fail, has the ajax call never got triggered or you saw some error?

Comment: @sza Fail meaning no outgoing HTTP request is made.

Comment: @GreatBigBore The error callback is being invoked by `.ajax()`, giving me state = 'rejected' and statusText = 'error'... having trouble digging up details why it failed.

Comment: @Dave I created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/N98Kz/ It works as expected, ajax calls were triggered without problem.

Comment: Have you cleared the browser's cache?

Comment: Thanks, I can see the fiddle making an outgoing network request for NY on my browser, too. But then why doesn't it work in my page?

Comment: @Jasen Yes, all my code is present on the page...

Comment: By default, unless you used `$.ajaxSetup` for default settings you're not showing us, you're using the `GET` method. As you're not specifying an explicit value for `cache`, and its default value is `true` according to jquery spec (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), your browser might still be working with an earlier (cached) response (even if the source code you see in the browser is up-to-date). I'd suggest using POST (if you an and if the server allows) and/or specifying `cache: false` explicity in the `$.ajax({...})` call, just to rule any funny stuff out.

Comment: @UweB You're onto something. When I set `type: 'POST'` and `cache: false` both, it worked. Even more strange, when I removed both of those again (because neither POSTing or disabling caching is preferable) the original code works. I surmise this has more to do with caching. Type up your findings into an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, unless you used $.ajaxSetup for default settings you're not showing us, you're using the GET method. As you're not specifying an explicit value for cache, and its default value is true according to jquery spec (api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax), your browser might still be working with an earlier (cached) response (even if the source code you see in the browser is up-to-date). I'd suggest using POST (if you an and if the server allows) and/or specifying cache: false explicity in the $.ajax({...}) call, just to rule any funny stuff out.

(copy/pasted from my comment as requested by the asker of the question)

Comment: *Copied from above...* When I set `type: 'POST'` and `cache: false` both, it worked. Even more strange, when I removed both of those again (because neither POSTing or disabling caching is preferable) the original code works. I surmise this has more to do with caching. I've decided to keep the original code now that the cache is properly cleared.